# Makefile, transforming filenames to collapse a filetree structure

Tags: makefile

Given the following directory structure

```
.
├── Makefile
├── test.test.io
│   └── topic
│       └── foo.yaml
└── foo.bar.us
    ├── topic
    │   └── foo.yaml
    │   └── bar.yaml
    └── other
        └── baz.yaml
```

I want to produce:

```
.
├── build
│   └── topic
│   │   └── test.test.io-foo.done
│   │   └── foo.bar.us-foo.done
│   │   └── foo.bar.us-bar.done
│   └── other
│       └── foo.bar.us-foo.done
```

I've started with something normalish like:

```
TOPIC_SOURCES := $(shell find . -path '*/topic/*.yaml')
TOPIC_DEPLOYS := $(TOPIC_SOURCES:%.yaml=build/%.done)

build/%.done: %.yaml
    @echo %< %@
```

But I'm kinda straching my head trying to figure out how to use the given tools to do the rest of the transform as I need to perform something akin to `sed -E 's|^./(.*)/topic/(.*).yaml|\1-\2.done|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make's wildcard-handling is not up to this. Use `shell` to invoke sed:

```
TOPIC_DEPLOYS := $(shell find . -path '*/topic/*.yaml' | sed 's|./\(.*\)/\(.*\)/\(.*\).yaml|\2/\1-\3.done|')
```